# Removing nav-links malware in Google Chrome on OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, virus, malware

I some how have been infected by the nav-links malware. It's a really annoying malware that shows up like a link on a text and when you click on it you are redirected to some advertised website like russianbrides.com

Been looking in the google chrome extensions and was not able to find it in the list so I was not able to delete it. Please share your experience of this annoying malware and how to get rid of it!

Comment: Is reinstalling Mac OS X an option?

Comment: Before you reinstall OS X try and delta the Chrome profile

Comment: reinstalling osx is not an option. It actually disappeared now since I inspected the element and entered the link: http://intext.nav-links.com/help.html and clicked on opt-out.

Comment: Found a solution for this now. 

1. You might have to remove some extensions for example in google chrome that you no longer use. And Go to: http://intext.nav-links.com/help.html and click on opt-out. Restart your browser. 

2. Browse to previous websites where the nav-links used to appear and check if it's still coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for this now.

1. You might have to remove some extensions for example in google chrome that you no longer use. And Go to: http://intext.nav-links.com/help.html and click on opt-out. Restart your browser.
2. Browse to previous websites where the nav-links used to appear and check if it's still coming up.

Comment: This recently started happening for me in Google Chrome and Chromium browsers on my Ubuntu system. Going to the link on the query button and clicking 'Opt-out' seems to do the trick, but I still don't understand how/why it started in the first place.

Comment: Why should we have to set a cookie to opt out of this junk??

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine had the same problem. It was happening because of some plug-in named something with ghost... I don't really remember. But here's what happened on her mac:

This appeared on both Chrome and Safari. When we **deinstalled the extension it on Safari** there were less links but still some apparent in Safari. When we **deinstalled the extension from Chrome as well**, it all was gone. So it seemed that this was an issue that could show up on other browsers as well although only installed on one. So **check your other browsers as well!**